# spark custom schema for csv file

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

can I define schema including subcolumns like below in spark for csv file and join two files on the basis of **KeyFields** and **NonKeyFields**

KeyFields       NonKeyFields
EmpId   DOB FirstName   LastName    Contact Loc1    Loc2    DOJ Comments    Supervisor

My sample data is in the following format
1242569,11-Sep-95,SANDEEP,KUMAR,9010765550,HYDERABAD,OFFSHORE,15-Jan-16,Passed Due,NAGALAKSHMI CHALLA

Comment: Can you give an example of the operation that you are trying to perform ?

Comment: I want to perform full outer join and filter operations over the joined dataframe on two sets of similar kind of dataset.
like filtering null records from right dataframe.

Comment: What I mean to say is, can you give a small example with a sample of your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it while reading the csv file like that:

```
df = sqlContext.read.load(<path of the file>, schema)
```